# How to call a variable defined inside main() but in outer scope

Tags: c++, scope, operation

Here is my code, im trying to call the variable defined inside the main(), but outside the current scope:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int asd = 10;  //***
    while (True) 
    { 
        int asd = 100;
        asd -= 1;   //***is it possible to use the 'asd' defined before while loop
        if (asd ==0) break;
    }
}
```

best regards
Eason

Comment: no it's not possible. you are redefining asd.

Comment: Call the variable something else.

Comment: note that your loop will never end as you are constantly redeclaring and setting `asd` to 100

Comment: Why do you need this? Just give the inner `asd` a different name.

Comment: @itwasntpete godel9, KevinDTimm, juanchopanza , on <c++ primer>,  it shows that i can call the variable defined in outer scope (even if i've redefined it in my inner scope), by using ::asd. so I'm just wondering if I can do it in a similar way?

Comment: still the answer is no.

Comment: @itwasntpete  ok,get it,  thanks for replying anyway XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The `int asd = 100;` is **masking** the old `asd` variable.

What you want (I suppose) is to just assign the value 100 to `asd`, which (and I'm sure you know this) you could simply do by writing `asd = 100;`.
There is, of course, one more issue: you would want to do that **before** the `while` loop - otherwise, you're going to have an infinite loop because at the beginning of every iteration the value of `asd` will be 100.

You're missing a `;` after `asd = 100`, by the way.

Comment: on <c++ primer>, it shows that i can call the variable defined in outer scope (even if i've redefined it in my inner scope), by using ::asd. so I'm just wondering if I can do it in a similar way?

Comment: ??, sry to bother u again, but do you have any clue to my first question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  OK, thanks alot, thats what i want to know

Answer (score 1):

If you REALY want to access the "outside" asd, before redefining it, create a reference to it:

```
int main()
{
   int i = 10;
   {
      int &ri = i;
      int i = 12;
      std::cout <<"i="<<i<<" ri = "<<ri<<std::endl;
      ++i;
      ++ri;
      std::cout <<"i="<<i<<" ri = "<<ri<<std::endl;
   }
   std::cout <<"i = " <<i <<std::endl;
}
```

will output:

```
i=12 ri = 10
i=13 ri = 11
i = 11
```